# How do I reverse this and make it so the code starts on LED7, aka farthest left led, and not on LED1, and then shifts left to right?

Tags: c, keil

I'm really new to c language programming and using Keil uVision in general, and I received an exercise where I have to reverse the code below and make it so it starts on LED7, the farthest led to the left, then shifts bit by bit to the right and goes back, and so on and so forth.

The current code starts on the right and goes to the left in a loop. When I tried reversing some of the code (for example, `for(i=1;i>1;i++)` into `i=7;i>7;i--`) and ran it, it flashed the first led on the right for 0.5s, and then stopped.

It restarts at random intervals. What do I do?

```
void Init_Device(void);

void main(void)
{
    U8 port=0x01,i;
    bit direction=0;
    Init_Device();
    initSYS();
    LCD_setTextSize(3);
    LCD_setCursor(80, 100);
    printf("P1 = ");

    while(1)
    {
        for(i=1;i>1;i++)
        {
            LCD_setCursor(160, 100);
            LCD_printNumb(port);
            printf(" = %d  ", (int)port);
            P1=~port;
            delay_ms(500);
            if(!direction)
                port<<=1;
            else
                port>>=1;
        }
        direction=~direction;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please double check the shown code. It cannot do the described behaviour. I doubt e.g. `for(i=1;i>1;i++)`. It would never execute anything.

Comment: Several things seem to be wrong. The conditions: "i>1" and "i>7". Then "i" is never used.

Comment: I bet the working code you describe starts on LED0, not LED1.

Answer (score 0):

Take the code which acts as you describe. That is however not the shown code.

Edit the working code by doing the following two changes.

Init `port` to MSB 0x80 (identifying "leftmost LED") instead of LSB 0x01 (identifying "rightmost LED").
Init `direction` to `~0`, i.e. the other one than `0`; which causes the code to start shifting in the other direction.